# Why is my conical/angle gradient image distorted?

Tags: python, numpy, math, python-imaging-library, gradient

I'm currently trying to create a conical gradient, and it kind of works. However, it doesn't look quite right and I can't wrap my hand around to why:

[image: sample output image]

The line that goes up from the center is slightly angled to the right and at the bottom there is a visible (not too noticable) line.

Code is as follows:

```
import math
import numpy
from PIL import Image


def newImg(w,h):
    data = numpy.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            p = [y,x]
            center = [h/2,w/2]
            angle = math.atan2(center[1]-p[1], center[0]-p[0])
            data[y,x] = angle*(255/math.pi/2)


    return data


image = Image.fromarray(newImg(2000,2000))
image.save('test.png')
image.show()
```

Oh, and another thing is that NumPy/Pillow swaps width and height, but that's something I can work around. Would be nice to have an explanation for that, though.

Comment: What do you mean NumPy/Pillow swaps width and height? If I run `image = Image.fromarray(newImg(1000,2000))`, I get an image with width `1000` and height `2000`!? NumPy array indexing, indeed, is first axis equals rows (`y` or "height") and second axis equals columns (`x` or "width"). But, you already managed to work out that properly!?

Comment: How should the image look like? A gradient based on the angle from center, as your code implements, I would not expect to look different. The shown picture looks like a spiral staircase, as I expect it. Can you manually create an approximation of what you expect? Juding from your description  "conical" I would expect a gradient based on distance, not on angle. Please clarify. (Off topic: I actually like your picture, it has a weirdly pretty 3D look.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Such a gradient based on distance, would be a "radial gradient" from my point of view, for example cf. https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/#radial-gradients vs. https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/#conic-gradients

Comment: @HansHirse Fair point. At least I would accept "radial" also as description of what I have in mind. Point is, OP should clarify, ideally show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you get negative values for `angle` from [`math.atan2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2), since its value range is `-pi ... pi`. Following, you get negative values in `data` causing integer underflows (since the `dtype` of `data` is `numpy.uint8`), which finally lead to numerical errors.

To prevent that, just add `math.pi` to each angle:

```py
angle = math.atan2(center[1]-p[1], center[0]-p[0]) + math.pi
```

So, the value range becomes `0 ... 2*pi` for `angle`, and properly `0 ... 255` for `data`. Of course, your gradient image is rotated by 180° then, but rotating the final image shouldn't be a problem, right?

The output image:

[image: Output]

Now, to further improve your code, get rid of the two (slooooow) loops, and use the vectorization abilities of NumPy:

```py
def newImg(w,h):
    x, y = numpy.meshgrid(range(w), range(h))
    x = w/2 - x
    y = h/2 - y
    angles = numpy.arctan2(y, x) + numpy.pi
    data = (angles * (255 / numpy.pi / 2)).astype(numpy.uint8)


    return data
```

There's a heavy speed-up for the `2000 x 2000` image, and the output image is identical.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you think that the output picture you show it the desired output OP wants? The question is not very clear, but I doubt it. (Off-topic: I like OPs picture better, it has less of an artificial look.)

Comment: @Yunnosch From my point of view, the main "problem" was this: _The line that goes up from the center is slightly angled to the right and at the bottom there is a visible (not too noticable) line._ Regarding the outputs: They're basically the same!? Rotate the provided image by 180° and open both images next to each other. I can't see any difference apart from the corrected "error".

Comment: This works, thanks! I suspected that it had to do with the number values since I ran into a similar problem earlier. Flipped "x = w/2 - x" to "x = x - w/2" (same for y) and that ofc flipped the image.