# Is there a way to fill a tk.Canvas Arc with gradient color instead of solid color?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The following scripts creates a `tk.Canvas` widget will a filled arc. The filled color is solid, i.e uniformly filled. I would like a graded appearance in either the radial or angular direction. Is there a way to do this? If so, how can it be done?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", pady=10)
canvas.create_arc(10, 10, 200, 200, style=tk.PIESLICE, start=0, extent=359, fill="yellow", outline="blue", width=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Current Appearance:
[image: Current Appearance]

Radial gradient:
[image: Radial gradient]

Angular gradient:
[image: Angular gradient]

Comment: There are no methods or attributes for mixing images with arc, unfortunately but it can be implemented fairly easily by overlaying arc on image then grouping them with shared tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `create_arc` accepts gradients as fill values. I think your best bet is to create an image and display it in your window.

Creating radial gradients is pretty straightforward with `drawSvg`. With `drawSvg` it is also easy to draw lines around and in your arc.

For conic/angular gradient, it isn't as simple. I found how to draw one in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169402/13525512). However, masking the corners (in case you want to display the circle only) doesn't work with `PIL.ImageTk`, which is why I had to use a buffer to stick with `tk.PhotoImage`. Also, drawing lines must be done separately.

```py
import tkinter as tk
# required for radial gradient:
import drawSvg as draw
# required for conic gradient:
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


def new_radial_gradient(w,h, start_color="green", stop_color="red"):
    d = draw.Drawing(2, 2, origin='center')
    gradient = draw.RadialGradient(0,0,1)
    gradient.addStop(0, start_color, 1)
    gradient.addStop(1, stop_color, 1)
    d.append(draw.Circle(0, 0, 1, fill=gradient))   # increase radius to 1.5 for a "square" appearence
    d.setRenderSize(w=w, h=h)
    return tk.PhotoImage(data=d.rasterize()._repr_png_())


def new_conic_gradient(w,h, start_color="green", stop_color="red"):
    x, y = np.meshgrid(range(w), range(h))
    x = w/2 - x
    y = h/2 - y
    angles = np.arctan2(y, x) + np.pi
    data = (angles * (255 / np.pi / 2)).astype(np.uint8)

    # transforming greyscale-array to rgb-array
    data = np.array([
                [x*np.array(mcolors.to_rgb(start_color)) + (255 - x)*np.array(mcolors.to_rgb(stop_color))
                 for x in r] for r in data
            ]).astype('uint8')

    tmp = Image.fromarray(data)

    # mask to keep a circle from any Image
    mask = Image.new('L', (w,h), 0)
    dr = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
    dr.ellipse((0, 0) + mask.size, fill=255)

    tmp.putalpha(mask)  # comment for a "square" appearence

    # using ByteIO with tk.PhotoImage because ImageTk loses the alpha layer
    buff = BytesIO()
    tmp.save(buff, format="png")

    return tk.PhotoImage(data=buff.getvalue())


# tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
CIRCLE_WIDTH = 500
CIRCLE_HEIGHT = 500

# radial
image1 = new_radial_gradient(CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_HEIGHT)
label1 = tk.Label(root, image=image1)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", pady=10)

# conic
image2 = new_conic_gradient(CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_HEIGHT)
label2 = tk.Label(root, image=image2)
label2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: refactoring code and adding colors as kwarg (now working for conic gradient too). Also if you use Windows, you'll have to install libcairo separately: install [uniconvertor](https://sk1project.net/uc2/download/) and make sure `libcairo-2.dll`
is in your `PATH`.